# ORA-28595: Extproc agent : Invalid DLL Path

Tags: oracle

We have some Oracle external procedure libraries (C language .so files, all 32-bit) that we are attempting to migrate from AIX/Oracle 11.2 to Linux/Oracle 12.2.  They recompiled successfully using gcc on Linux.  While those libraries worked fine in AIX/Oracle, we are getting "ORA-28595: Extproc agent : Invalid DLL Path" error when testing this in the Linux/12c environment.

The Linux listener.ora contains:

```
SID_LIST_EXTERNAL_PROCEDURE_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = swm1)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client32)
      (PROGRAM=extproc)
      (ENVS="EXTPROC_DLLS=ANY,LIBPATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client32/lib,LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/swms/curr/lib,TRACE_LEVEL=ON")
 )
 )
```

### After each test, we can see in the hs/log traces content like:

```
Oracle Corporation --- THURSDAY  OCT 18 2018 16:37:43.679

    Version 12.2.0.1.0

HOA 10/18 16:37:43.679414000: (horcrase_AllocStackElt) Entered!
HOA 10/18 16:37:43.679437000: (horcrase_AllocStackElt) Exiting...
HOA 10/18 16:37:43.679448000: (horcrpuoe_PushOciEnv) Entered!
HOA 10/18 16:37:43.679457000: (horcrpuoe_PushOciEnv) Exiting...
HOA 10/18 16:37:43.679465000: (horcries_InitExtprocSession) Exiting...
HOA 10/18 16:37:43.679486000: (hotkisc_InitSessionContext) Exiting...
HOA 10/18 16:37:43.679496000: (hotkec_EstablishConnection) Entered!
2018/10/18-16:37:43.679812000: Entered shorcsju_spawn_jssu_unix
  HS: Parent extproc argv[1] = (DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)))
  HS: Parent extproc called nsgetaddr, addr = (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=#20938.1.933310848))
  HS: Parent extproc received the IN param, flags_horrx = 0x1000
0: 31303030                             [1000]
  HS: Parent extproc is falling back to the old behavior with connect string = (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=BEQ)(PROGRAM=/u01/app/oracle/produ
ct/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/extproc)(ARGV0=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/extproc)(ARGS='(DESCRIPTION=(LOCAL=YES)(ADDRESS=(P
ROTOCOL=BEQ)))'))
  HS: Parent extproc called nsbequeath! status = 0
2018/10/18-16:37:43.695384000: Exiting shorcsju_spawn_jssu_unix, rc=0
  HS: Parent extproc is calling exit(0)!!!
```

---

It is curious that it is loading the 64 bit bin/extproc even though we explicit provided the 32-bit ORACLE_HOME in listener.ora.

While we see trace content like that above in the $ORACLE_HOME/hs/logs, the external_procedure_listener/trace/* files are not showing new trace content when running the tests.

Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: I'm not very familiar, but it sounds like you're following these directions... are you running the 32-bit listener? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/UNXAR/ldr_demo.htm#UNXAR240

Comment: That is what the specification of "ORACLE_HOME = /u01/app/oracle/product/12.2.0/client32" is supposed to do.

Comment: Well, `dbhome_1/bin/listener` starts `dbhome_1/bin/extproc`, and `dbhome_1/bin/extproc` starts `dbhome_1/lib/libusercode.so` -- at least that's how it is known to work. All these components are of the same bitness (64).

Comment: So you should recompile your plugins with `-m64` option (64-bit).

Comment: Our DBA team found Oracle Doc ID 2424136.1, at https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2424136.1
There are two workarounds in that doc that may help.  I will update with results after their changes are applied.  Thanks.